# Connect a Database with an Amazon VPC from local

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

Just created an VPC for EKS Cluster and started RDS PostgreSQL instance with custom VPC.

Custom VPC has Subnets.
My Custom VPC has Internet Gateway attached.

EKS and RDS is in same VPC so they have internal communication.
My problem is that i want to connect to RDS from my local machine and i am unable. Regarding the problem i have created a new Security Group with Inbound Rules for PostgreSQL.

```
PostgreSQL  TCP 5432    0.0.0.0/0   –
```

Im still unable to connect

**UPDATE**

1. RDS is Publicly accessible
2. Security group allows access to RDS

Answer (score 0):

To be able to connect to the RDS database remotely you need to select "yes" option for the "Public Accessibility" setting for you database. Here are some additional configurations that need to be taken into account ([form AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.WorkingWithRDSInstanceinaVPC.html)):

> - If you want your DB instance in the VPC to be publicly accessible, you
>   must enable the VPC attributes DNS hostnames and DNS resolution.
> - Your VPC must have a VPC security group that allows access to the DB
>   instance.
> - The CIDR blocks in each of your subnets must be large enough to
>   accommodate spare IP addresses for Amazon RDS to use during
>   maintenance activities, including failover and compute scaling.

Best,
Stefan

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, i have enabled Public Accessibility for database but the same situation.

Comment: OK, That is good! Let's check your networking then - can you confirm that your RDS instance is running in a public subnet (a subnet that has route to the internet gateway)?

Comment: @MikheilJaniashvili I also edited my answer with additional information.

Answer (score 0):

In order to connect to RDS instances from the internet you need to do these 3 things

1. Deploy your RDS instance in a "public" subnet. This means the subnet must have an Internet Gateway attached to it so it can respond properly to outbound requests
2. In your RDS instance under Connectivity, extend the Additional configuration section, and then choose Publicly accessible.
3. Make sure the security group allows access to your RDS instance.

Note: exposing a database to public access is not secure. What I recommend you to do is create a proxy with `haproxy` or a VPN.

Comment: First of all, Thank you for your time.
1. I have Both Public/Private Subnet, attached with Internet Gateway.
2. Enabled Publicly Accessible
3. In Security Group Inbound Listens to my Ip
still unable to connect, or ping.

Comment: what happens when you ping your RDS endpoint? do you get a private or public ip?

Comment: i get public ip.

Comment: are you trying to log in with the master user?